# selecting specific substring and creating new column with 0 and 1

Tags: r

```
a<- c("01:07", "01:01", "08:01", "06:01")
b <- c("03:04", "05:03", "06:03", "03:07")
df <- data.frame(a,b)
df
```

Hi, I m trying to compare these two columns on the basis of specific substring in the columns as "01" (but should not select the row which has 07 or 08 in the same string), similarly in b column selecting the substring "03" (but should not select that row which has 04 or 05 in the same string) and give me a new column as 0 and 1.

Like above df, if we see, row 1 has 01:07 and 03:04 (so as I want to select 01 and 03 but it also have 07 and 04) so the new column should be 0.
But if we see the second row it has 01:01 (no- 07/08 ) and second row 05:03 (no -04/06) so the new columns gives 1. so the new column will be 0,1,0,1

Comment: Please post wanted output

Comment: for row b, do you not want 04/05 or 04/06? your two paragraphs don't agree with each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe with `strsplit`.

```
fun <- function(x, y){
    x <- strsplit(as.character(x), ":")
    y <- strsplit(as.character(y), ":")
    i1 <- sapply(x, function(.x) .x[1] == "01" & !(.x[2] %in% c("07", "08")))
    i2 <- sapply(y, function(.y) .y[1] == "03" & !(.y[2] %in% c("04", "05")))
    as.integer(i1 | i2)
}

fun(df$a, df$b)
[1] 0 1 0 1

df$c <- fun(df$a, df$b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `grepl`:

```
grepl("01", df$a)&(-grepl("07", df$a) | -grepl("08", df$a)) & 
  grepl("03", df$b)&(-grepl("04", df$b) | -grepl("06", df$b))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `grepl` for this to check for your structure. There's probably a more elegant way, but this seems to work:

```
inds1 <- grepl("01", df$a) & !(grepl("(07|08)", df$a))
inds2 <- grepl("03", df$b) & !(grepl("(04|05)", df$b))

df$c <- (inds1 | inds2) * 1
# [1] 0 1 1 1
```

`inds1` checks two things and returns `TRUE` only when both conditions are met: The string contains `01` and *doesn't* contain `07` nor `08`.

`inds2` applies the same idea, but with the other criteria.

`df$c` will then be filled with a row-wise check whether one of the values meets the criteria of the column they're in

Answer (score 0):

OP might need to clarify his logic (row 2 has 05 in `b`, so it should be zero?), but one might use negative lookbehind and lookahead:

```
logic1 = grepl("(?<!(07|08):)01(?!:(07|08))", df$a, perl = TRUE) 
logic2 = grepl("(?<!(04|05):)03(?!:(04|05))", df$b, perl = TRUE)

df$c = as.integer(logic1 & logic2)

#       a     b c
# 1 01:07 03:04 0
# 2 01:01 05:03 0
# 3 08:01 06:03 0
# 4 06:01 03:07 1
```